# Maintenance Mode Conflict Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter project I am have made a maintenance mode module and it works with the database. value 1 is maintenance mode on value 0 maintenance mode off.

I am trying to get MY_Controller to work with my maintenance mode controller. But there keeps on being page load error conflict.

My Controller Not Redirecting If Maintenance Mode Is On And Admin Is Logged out It Should Redirect to maintenance controller. if I do this if `(!$this->configs->get('config_maintenance')) {` then redirects ok but show page load error.

My Controller.

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('configs');
        $this->load->library('user');

        // For Front End Controllers Only Have extends MY

        if ($this->configs->get('config_maintenance')) {

            if (!$this->user->isLogged()) {

                return true;

                redirect('/');

            } else {

                return false;

                redirect('maintenance');

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Maintenance Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maintenance extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        if ($this->configs->get('config_maintenance')) {

            if (!$this->user->isLogged()) {

                redirect('/');

            } else {

                $this->on();

            }

        } else {

            redirect('/');
        }

    }

    public function on() {
        echo "Maintenance Mode On";
    }

    public function off() {
        echo "Maintenance Mode Off";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of this is not pure codeigniter syntax, It looks like you're using HMVC. please edit your question and tag to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

My maintenance mode issue is now fixed here is how I done it on the home controller I use extends MY_Controller on the Maintenance controller I used MX_Controller working now.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maintenance extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('isLogged')) {

            redirect('/');

        } else {

            $this->on();
        }

    }

    public function on() {
        echo "Maintenance Mode On";
    }

    public function off() {
        echo "Maintenance Mode Off";
    }

}
```

MY_Controller

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->maintenance();
    }

    public function maintenance() {

        if ($this->configs->get('config_maintenance')) {

            if (!$this->session->userdata('isLogged')) {

                redirect('maintenance');

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        }

    }
}
```